# How to completely disable tonemaps and color management for custom OETFs and tonemaps

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management

As you know, Blender has a built-in filmic LUT and sRGB OETF.
To go even further, I would like to add light adaptation, tonemaps and OETF directly to the renderer's output linear HDR image.
How do I do this?

Comment: "completely disable tonemaps and color management" - don't know how to do it, but if I save a render as EXR file (which is linear) and then open it with Photoshop, it says the embedded profile doesn't match the working color space, and I can choose to either use the embedded profile, convert it to the working color space or disable color management completely... maybe you can do this in other software as well?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "light adaptation, tonemaps and OETF" are, but 32bit float EXR format cannot even save anything else than what you want. It saves linear color only so render or bake whatever you need to EXR.

Raw rendered images come from the Render Layers node, then Blender applies color transforms during viewing or saving the compositing result. Color transforms get applied when you save images with most formats, except EXR. EXR stores raw data from the render(or compositing) without color management, because it can save all 32bit values(as precise as they come from render) while lower bit depths require colors to be compressed to smaller range with tonemapping, color grading, LUTs, OETFs(not sure how 'optic' part applies here, but why not) or whatever fancy term you want to use for this, anyway, that's just fitting the color values to smaller range in hopefully meaningful way so we can see everything.

So you can:

- Set up render with compositing so Render Layers node-> compositing magic -> color management -> image (like JPEG)

or

- Render everything to EXR and do compositing to the rendered files so Render -> EXR files -> Load EXR files back to Blender instead of Render Layers node -> compositing magic -> color management get applied -> image

Filmic transforms get applied with color management. Color management happens automaticaly to saved files, Viewport and Image editor when you view compositing results in it. If you wanted to "do color management" yourself(not recommending it), you can set display device and everything else to "none" in the color management settings. That's probably a bad idea.

You could also look into other color managemt solutions than Filmic. They exist.

> Blender's color management is based on the OpenColorIO library. By
> using the same OpenColorIO configuration in multiple applications, the
> same color spaces and transforms will be available for consistent
> results.

[https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#:~:text=Blender's%20color%20management%20is%20based,be%20available%20for%20consistent%20results](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#:%7E:text=Blender%27s%20color%20management%20is%20based,be%20available%20for%20consistent%20results)

See the nice diagrams of how it works there as well.

Comment: Customizing the tonemap function is necessary for film simulation.

Comment: In what software do you want to do that? If I understood you correctly, you want to leave render color values completely untouched out of the render so you can process the renders in other software than Blender, is that correct?

Comment: I believe custom tonemapping are possible by creating a tonemap node on the composite node. To do this, the picture must be RAW on the beginning of the compositing node.

Comment: It's RAW from Render Layers node. You can process image from it with various nodes and output as render, but if you want to render first and then do compositing while looking at the result, you should use EXR format. EXR format saves all info from the render as it is before any color transforms done by color management. You can also render passes and save them to Multilayer EXR so you have control over separate diffuse, glossy and other components and also can use Cryptomatte masks. Color management transforms like Filmic get applied to what you view or save after compositing.

Comment: I tried to update the answer.